# Geoserver - SLD style with aliases

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm new at Geoserver.

I've data in postgis tables and using QGIS OpenGeo plugin to publish data to Geoserver. 
Postgis tables --> QGIS (Opengeo) --> Geoserver

I would like to give a different name (alias) to the columns of my tables and I did that at QGIS Layer Properties, but when I save the style in a .sld file but such information is not stored in the file  (in a .qml style file all the information is stored).

So, as anyone know if it's possible to give aliases to columns at geoserver (or any kind of workaround...) ?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know it is not possible to give aliases in columns with Geoserver.
If you are consulting this data on a Web Map through a WMS, it's possible develop a Info Tool with a GetFeatureInfo Template instead - see [this article](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html)

Comment: We prefer long answers here. Please explain how to implement template and why it answers the question

Comment: The answer is correct, there is no notion of attribute aliases in GeoServer at the moment (it would be possible to develop it, not too hard), and the only way to do some level of aliasing is using GetFeatureInfo with HTML output and a custom template